# Why doesn't Windows delete the hibfile.sys?

Tags: windows, hibernate

I hibernate my computer once a month, if even that much.

Windows keeps my hibfile.sys forever and takes up 16gb of my SSD.

Why isn't it smart enough to delete the file after rebooting from hibernation?

Answer (score 4):

`hiberfil.sys` is used to allocate disk space for hibernation. Otherwise you could use all disk space for your own purposes and make hibernation impossible even though it's enabled.

If you want to hibernate once a month, then disable hibernation and re-enable it when you need it.

Comment: why can't it do that on its own? and show me the same message when I try to hibernate that it would show me if I wanted to enable hibernation without enough disk space?

Comment: @h.alex Do you want OS to randomly disable features to save RAM/disk space/CPU cycles/(insert any resource name)? "This program has been removed to save disk space. Please re-download it". "Your CPU is usually under light load, so 3 cores were disabled on previous reboot to save power. Please save your work and reboot again to enable more cores". "Hibernation is enabled, but you don't have enough disk space. Please delete some of your files". (this is the moment when you go "Aww ****, not again... I *need* all these files you stupid computer! *Damn Microsoft!*)

Answer (score 1):

Windows never knows when you are going to hibernate it, so what is the point in deleting it? It doesn't know you'll only do it once a month.

Comment: I think the OP wonders why it is not created when the system goes into hibernate mode and delete after resuming from it. That way it will not use a significant part of a SSD when hibernate is not in use.

The obvious added risk to that would be that you could not hibernate if the disk was full, but at that point that should be a minor issue.

Comment: This. How would you even tell the user it’s not possible now because the disk space is low? Would he understand? No. And what about a notebook with low battery? Want to lose your work? Didn’t think so.

Comment: @DanielB Microsoft is only one of the largest software companies in the world. They are not able to allocate resources to create two different hibernation modes - one for laptops, another for desktops. You have power options in windows, why cant there be a setting there - delete my hibfile.sys after reboot. With a warning 'if u use up your diskspace hibernation will not be possible'. Pre-emptive disk usage, I mean - it's just horrible from so many points of view.

Comment: So, @Hennes yes, exactly - if I want to hibernate, it can tell me 'sorry dude, u haven't enough disk space'.